# cargar base de datos con mas de 10000 registros - php

Tags: php

buen dia, mi get carga sin problemas los registros de la base de datos pero cuando cargo grandes cantidades de registros se me queda bloqueada .
¿como hago para que me cargue grandes cantidades de registros sin problemas?

```html
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $query="select * from proveedores where id=".$_GET['id'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        $query="select * from proveedores";
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: Bloqueada quiere decir que no los carga o que pasa? puede ser que de timeout?

Comment: si, es que son tantos registros que el query no alcanza a cargarlo todos o se demora un mundo de tiempo en cargar los registros

Comment: mil registros son pocos.. salvo que la informacion que estes trayendo sea enorme.. si no el problema puede estar en otro lado...

Comment: los registros son mas de 10.000 , y al ser tan grande la cantidad de registros mi query se cuelga.

Comment: lei mal.. perdon.. seguro tenes un timeout.. o la respuesta que te dieorn.. seguro necesitas tantos datos sin paginar?

Comment: Veo que seleccionas todas las columnas de esa tabla. ¿Hay alguna de ellas que tenga un peso considerable con demasiados datos?  Piensa en solo escoger las columnas estrictamente necesarias para empezar, y si luego necesitas más datos porque alguien hace click o algo, entonces venirlos a buscar despues mediante ajax o lo que sea.  Si las necesitas todas entonces planteate dejar la consulta ya realizada en algun archivo del servidor cada x tiempo, e irla a buscar alli despues. Si con tan solo tu ejecutando esa consulta ya te peta, imaginate si son 2 o 100 usuarios haciendo las misma consulta.

Comment: Aún así, el hecho que necesites todas las filas diria que no tiene demasiado sentido. Aún imaginando que lo consiguieras, la carga de una página web con tantos datos a la vez seria muy lenta por la cantidad de MB que podria implicar y tus usuarios perderian la paciencia, a la vez que harias sufrir a los navegadores si ademas les pones más cosas a realizar con esos datos en javascript o lo que sea. Si necesitas realizar cálculos con ellas mejor lo haces con otro tipo de consultas que ya los devuelvan sin tener que descargarlos todos.

Comment: Yo supongo que es un exportar o algo similar y por eso es de 10k de registros, algo que también podrías probar es hacerlo con un "generar reporte" y que luego se genere y solo descargarlo. Otra cosa es que el resultado sea un csv en vez de un json, por que el json igual se tiene que cargar todo en memoria a diferencia del csv que se puede leer por filas.

Comment: A no ser que este código sea para la NASA, el mismo es inviable. En un dispositivo normal, renderizar y moverse entre 10,000 registros va a ser muy muy tedioso. Si **realmente** necesitas **trabajar/mostrar** 10,000 registros a la vez, vas a tener que usar **paginación**, dividiendo por ejemplo en bloques de 100 o de 200 o de 500. Y si tienes que hacer cosas como ordenar esos registros por una columna X o una columna Y dinámicamente (como las tablas de Excel), tendrás que idear algo más refinado.

Comment: Lo mejor para procesos como éste, es prepararlo de forma que se pueda ejecutar por lotes (varias ejecuciones del script PHP), de forma que evitas problemas de timeout, out of memory,... Hay que darle un poco al coco, eso sí, si es la primera vez que lo intentas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que sea un tema de memoria, o sea actualmente estás leyendo la tabla y la estás volcando a memoria, luego estás ejecutando `json_encode` que lo convierte a json, lo guardas en una variable y eso lo devuelves, eso hace que sea demasiado para el servidor:

Lo que podemos hacer es ir leyendo la bd e ir mandando linea por linea al cliente, eso reduce tu carga de memoria, para ello puedes hacer lo siguiente (no lo he probado, me avisas si hay un error):

```php
echo '['; // inicias el json

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from proveedores");

$numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo json_encode($row); // codificas y mandas al cliente cada linea
    $counter += 1;
    if ($counter != $numResults) {
        echo ',';
    }

    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
echo ']'; // finalizas el json
```

EDIT (PDO):

Si lo que devuelve `getMetodo` es un objeto de tipo PDOStatement, entonces debería quedar así:

```php
echo '['; // inicias el json

$result = metodoGet($query);

$numResults = $result->rowCount();
$counter = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch()) {

    echo json_encode($row); // codificas y mandas al cliente cada linea
    $counter += 1;
    if ($counter != $numResults) {
        echo ',';
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
echo ']'; // finalizas el json
```

Quedando en tu script de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header( 'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $query="select * from proveedores where id=".$_GET['id'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        $query="select * from proveedores";
        echo '['; // inicias el json

        $result = metodoGet($query);

        $numResults = $result->rowCount();
        $counter = 0;

        while($row = $result->fetch()) {

            echo json_encode($row); // codificas y mandas al         cliente cada linea
            $counter += 1;
            if ($counter != $numResults) {
                echo ',';
            }
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
        echo ']'; // finalizas el json
    }

    exit();

}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: pero dentro de mi query como quedaria ?

Comment: Tienes que modificar el método `metodoGet` para que no se cargue toda esa query en memoria, si no que lo podamos iterar así como en mi código de ejemplo para traer linea por linea. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` esa línea hace la magia, solo guarda en memoria una fila `$row`

Comment: pero como se visualizaría en mi GET? ya que no encuentro como remplazar mi get por el codigo que subiste.

Comment: Perdón acabo de agregar como sería con tu código.

Comment: en el query que actualizo no se ve la conexion a proveedores  ni a la base de datos

Comment: Entendía que eso lo manejabas dentro de tu `métodoGet` el cual devuelve un objeto de tipo PDOStatememt

Comment: podrias adaptarlo al script que yo subi ?

Comment: Revisa de nuevo por favor

Comment: si funciona, pero el cargar los 10.000 registros se sigue demorando igual que mi query

Comment: Si los datos los estás regresando a un front-end o dispositivo, te vas a comer la memoria de la computadora. No deberías estar retornando tantos registros. Recomiendo ampliamente un sistema de paginado, esto para efectos de optimización tanto en la consulta como en los recursos usados del front.

Comment: Pues claro que se demora, el echo no se va enviando miestras el script no haya terminado, se almacena en el bufer de salida y espera a que termine el script para volcarlo todo. No hay apenas diferencia entre ambas cosas (con echo o sin echo), **a menos** que uses `flush()` y/o `ob_flush()` mientras lo haces, pero debes acompañarlo de un `header( 'Content-type:` lo que sea (en este caso json) al principio antes del bucle de salida de los echo. Y tampoco me las tengo todas que vaya a funcionar como esperais. Y no en todos los browsers creo.

Comment: +1 masterguru, lo había olvidado, ya lo agregué.

Comment: Como decia, sigo pensando que igualmente no va a funcionar, porque el json se cierra despues del bucle, por lo tanto lo que vaya recibiendo dudo que lo sepa procesar si no esta bien cerrado mientras lo recibe.  No lo veo una solución, lo siento, pero si funciona de alguna forma yo contento :-)

Comment: Jajajaja si, de acuerdo, igual cargar al front con tanta data es un abuso, pero me imagino y espero que lo que quiera es descargar/exportar la data.

Comment: Si lo que quiere es exportar datos que use el mysqldump, que es mucho mas seguro y rapido y facil de usar... y tambien lo puede lanzar desde php mediante system() o algun otro tipo de llamadas al sistema.  No hace falta reinventar la rueda para eso :-)

Comment: Hacer SELECT de uno en uno afectará al rendimiento, estaría mejor coger varios cada vez, quizá 100, 500,... No obstante, lo mejor para evitar problemas es preparar un proceso que se pueda ejecutar por lotes, esto elude timeout, out of memory,...